# Is effervescent a pejorative when describing a person

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language

My colleagues and I have been talking about whether or not "effervescent" is a pejorative when used to describe someone.

To provide context, one of the people who works in my office is a high-energy and bubbly person but they aren't flighty or whimsical (they're grounded, well-adjusted). We've been trying to find the best adjective to describe them and wondering whether people thought effervescent sounded vaguely insulting.

Also, anyone have any good recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, I have heard "effervescent" applied as a polite euphemism to someone with frequent flatulence, but I can't verify whether the usage is common or widespread. Excluding that usage, I would think "effervescent" was fine.

Comment: Without a doubt, "effervescent" would be taken as a positive characteristic. Such people are often a joy to be around.

Comment: @cascabel I don’t think it’s always positive. See my comments on the answer, which I DV’d.

Comment: @Xanne Hhmmnn...maybe this Q is mainly POB.

Comment: There’s serious literature in linguistics on vocabulary relating to men and women (as well as gender).  So relegating it to a matter of opinion is evading the issue,

Comment: Erm, @Xanne  The OP took pains to avoid gender issues : "one of the people", "they", "them" "they are"...

Comment: Exactly, @cascabel. The OP also avoids saying to whom this person is being described. Without this context, it is not possible to say whether the term is insulting (albeit indirectly) or not.

Comment: Whether something is pejorative depends a lot on tone of voice. "What about X?" "Well, she's a bit ... [winces] ... effervescent."

Answer (score 1):

Most dictionaries, as Collins, define ***[effervescent](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/effervescent)*** with a positive connotation:

> If you describe someone as effervescent, you mean that they are lively, entertaining, enthusiastic, and exciting.
>   ***[approval]***
>
> - *...her winning smile and effervescent personality.
>     America is the most intellectually, artistically and politically effervescent of nations.*

Comment: Very odd to characterize a nation as having a facial expression.  France’s peevish pout, Norway’s frightening frown?  I suspect the quote is a rewrite that originally referenced pop culture and citizens, not the country.

Comment: My sense is that effervescent, like feisty, is a word more easily applied to women than men, and is a way of not taking a woman seriously; and thus risks being pejorative.